# Devise requires 2 password confirmations to edit user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I enter the password confirmation and the current password, the update works. But when I only enter one of them (since I don't want to change my password), the update fails.
[image: edit user view]

Answer (score 1):

Try only filling the `current password` field (the last one in your form) and leave the other two blank. Should work.

Comment: oh wow haha! that's interesting. Thanks heaps =) guess I'll have to write some JS code to empty that field.

Comment: I usually hide and disable  those two fields and let users make them visible and editable again with a button `change password`

Comment: yeah I'd probably implement something similar.